# If I knew him, I would say (would have said) hello

Tags: conditional-constructions

What is the difference between these 2 sentences:

> If I knew him, I **would say** hello.
>   If I knew him, I **would have said** hello.

I found the second sentence here :
https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/conditional-sentences/exceptions

Answer (score 2):

If I **knew** him, I **would say** hello. But I don't know him so I don't say hello.
We **say this now** about a situation. [called: conditional type 2,for a hypothetical condition and its probable result)

If I **had known**  him, I **would have said** hello. But I didn't know him so I didn't say hello.
We **say this now about a past situation**. [also called conditional type 3, a hypothetical condition in the past ]

If I **knew** him, I **would have** said hello.= **can be called many things**: ungrammatical, non-standard, uneducated or even "dialectal" in cases other speech features are present. This is heard a lot in speech when the speakers actually mean: If I had known him.....

Kindly note: the present is called conditional 1: I if know him, I will say hello. Conditional type 1 for a possibility and/or general truth.

There are much fancier names and descriptions for all this. There are even mixed conditionals, but the posted sentence is not one.

Comment: (–1) *If I knew him, I would have said hello* is very much grammatical (see CaGEL, p.752).

Comment: No, it really is not, even if Americans use it all the time. It is completely ungrammatical and, if you think about it, makes no sense regardless of what CaGEL,p.752 says. "if I knew him" can only be uttered in the present and cannot go with a past perfect. "If I knew him, I would say hello."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83294/discussion-on-answer-by-lambie-if-i-knew-him-i-would-say-would-have-said-hell).

Answer (score 0):

> If you were at a tattoo parlor getting "ELL" tattooed on your left buttock, and someone you knew walked in, what would you do?
>   —If I knew him, I would say hello.
>   Were you always so friendly and outgoing? Would you have done the same ten years ago?
>   —Yes, if I knew him, I would have said hello.
>   How about this morning? You seemed pretty grumpy, like you hated the world.
>   —Yes, even this morning. If I knew him, I would have said hello.

Comment: Were you always [in the past]; would you have done the same ten years ago? Yes, if I had known him, I would've. If I knew is present. Whether linguists agree or not. No professor would leave: If those particular troops **fought** in World War II, they ***would have seen*** major battles in the Pacific or in Europe. It has to be: had fought.

Comment: @Lambie:  In AmE, **if I knew** can also be used with the past situation; it's not ungrammatical there. https://books.google.com/books?id=xVVhXgy9xawC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22if+i+knew%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3s-vl2MLdAhWwTt8KHfnaCZsQ6AEIQDAD#v=onepage&q=%22if%20i%20knew%22&f=false